Python Speech recognition : Microphone detected only once, the first time the program runs
I am using the speech recognition library to detect speech. I am using streamlit for the interface. A button triggers the speech recognition process. The first time it works fine.The audio is recognized and transcribed.
edit: When I press the button a second time, nothing happens. The mic is not being detected
At this point I don't know if the problem is with streamlit or with the speech_recognition part.
This is the function doing the SR:
import speech_recognition as sr

r= sr.Recognizer()
def get_audio():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.pause_threshold=0.5
        audio=r.listen(source)
        said=""


    try:
        print("inside Try")
        said=r.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR")
        print(said)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Exception: Google speech recogniton could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print(f"Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service: {e}")
    return said


The second time it's not even entering the Try block
This is an excerpt from the call to get_audio():
if st.button("Click-me to speak"):
        text= get_audio()
        query = st.text_input("Input your prompt here: ", text, key="transcription")
        if query:
            submit = True


I noticed that the second time I press the button, the microphone on my computer is not activated. The first time I can see it highlighted in yellow.

It may be due to built-in Streamlit Caching mechanism. Since the r object (Recognizer) is created outside the function, it might not reset properly between your function calls. So let's try creating a new Recognizer object inside the get_audio() function. This way every time it will be called to ensure a fresh state like below:
import speech_recognition as sr
import streamlit as st

def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()  # Create a new Recognizer object each time
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.pause_threshold = 0.5
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""
    try:
        print("inside Try")
        said = r.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR")
        print(said)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Exception: Google speech recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print(f"Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service: {e}")
    return said

if st.button("Click-me to speak"):
    text = get_audio()
    query = st.text_input("Input your prompt here: ", text, key="transcription")
    if query:
        submit = True


Yes the problem might be Streamlit. I ended up running a Flask app and the speech recognition works fine. Thanks fot your help
